# Inserting content with CSS a second time?

Tags: css

Is it possible to insert -- dynamically generated -- content with CSS into the same website **a second time**, let's say a div-container like this: `<div id="duplicate-me">dynamically generated content</div>`

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Well, there is not much to it. This is it. I need a couple of div-containers displayed a second time. I would like to find a solution with CSS for avoiding difficulties with version updates of the CMS if I have to change the PHP-code otherwise

Comment: CSS is not for content manipulation, so you are wrong trying to find a CSS solution for this

Comment: If you look at a homepage as a house, HTML is the building material, CSS is painting and placing the building material, and javascript is the wiring and plumbing to make the building materials interactive. If you want to interact with the DOM, you need javascript.

Answer (score 2):

CSS is used to style content that exists or will eventually exist on a page. It can't load or insert dynamic content to a page. It can control showing/hiding content on a page, but the content needs to be placed there first (with the exception of psuedo-classes, but that's not really "dynamic"). As others have mentioned, Javascript/jQuery is what you are needing to use to achieve what you are wanting.

Comment: I don't see why my answer was down-voted, as I don't see how it is either incorrect or doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pseudo element's` in CSS we can kind of create an element and style it in CSS. But then this has it's own limitations.

`Javascript` is what will essentially help you achieve this using `document.createElement()` method  and other methods line `appendChild()` etc

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how the OP should use psuedo elements and/or a JavaScript solution instead of plainly stating that?

Comment: I don't think we can create pseudoelements in css, but we can only select them with `::after, ::before, :nth_child(n)`, but javascript sure works

Answer (score 1):

CSS cannot be used for duplicating, but you can use javascript to duplicate div,p or any other element. We do it like
In the html file

```html
<head>
<!--all other stuff-->
<script src='sketch.js'></script>
</head>
```

in the sketch.js file

```js
var dupElem = document.createElement('div');
dupElem.id = "duplicate-me";
document.body.appendChild(dupElem);

//to manipulate the text content we do
dupElem.textContent = "some lorem ipsum"

//or else you can do a for loop
for (let i = 0;i < 3;i++){
    document.body.appendChild(dupElem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a copy of a node element but you need Javascript to do that.

```
<div class="duplicate-me">dynamically generated content</div>
```

In your Javascript:

```
let nodeToClone = document.getElementsByClassName("duplicate-me")[0];
let newClone = nodeToClone.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(newClone);
```

Please note that id needs to be unique in the document. That is why I used class.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) you can learn more about clone.

Answer (score 0):

O.K., JavaScript then. I'll look into it. Thank you for the answers. :-)